# How can I activate a list item by clicking on a checkbox?

Tags: javascript, dom

I want to check  a checkbox and a class will be added to a list item that will  reduce the opacity and also line-through the list item to show completion of task.

This is what I did but it is not working.

```js
var btn = document.querySelector('.btn') 
var inputValue = document.querySelector('input');
var ulContainer = document.querySelector('.ul-container');
var input = document.querySelector('.check-input');

console.log(input);

var li = document.createElement('li'); // EVENTLISTENERS

btn.addEventListener('click', generateToDo);

input.addEventListener('click', complete); // FUNCTION 

function generateToDo() {
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.classList.add('div-1');
  var ul = document.createElement('ul');
  li = document.createElement('li');
  var z = inputValue.value;
  li.textContent = z;
  ul.appendChild(li);
  div.appendChild(ul);
  var input = document.createElement('input');
  input.type = 'checkbox';
  input.classList.add('check-input');
  div.appendChild(input);
  var dleBtn = document.createElement('button');
  dleBtn.innerHTML = '';
  dleBtn.classList.add('btn-trash');
  div.appendChild(dleBtn);
  ulContainer.appendChild(div);
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
  <div class="ul-container center"></div>
</div>`
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to do something like this:

```js
let list = document.querySelector('ul');
list.addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
  if (ev.target.tagName === 'LI') {
    ev.target.classList.toggle('checked');
  }
}, false);
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul li {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  padding: 12px 8px 12px 40px;
  background: #eee;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.2s;

  user-select: none;
}


ul li.checked {
  opacity: 0.3;
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<ul id="myUL">
  <li>Todo1</li>
  <li class="checked">Todo2</li>
  <li>Todo3</li>
</ul>
```

This probably isn't the best solution, but good enough for a simple todo app.

A complete todo app can be found [here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_todolist.asp).

Comment: the thing is I want to create a div, li, delete btn and the checkbox when a user click on a add button. so if a user  check the checkbox  a class will be added to  the li is which the todo to show completion of the task.

Answer (score 0):

1. First, I see you've added a `"div-1"` class to your to-do container div, so I'm assuming you would expect the next added to-do to have a class of `"div-2"`, then `"div-3"`, and so on. Correct? If so, there's the first issue. Currently, all the generated to-dos will have the same `"div-1"` class, so in the `generateToDo` function you must first increment the class name for each newly generated todo.
2. Then, if I understand correctly, you want to hold the logic for completing the to-do in a function called `complete()`. You need to move `input.addEventListener('click', complete)` to the `generateToDo` function, so that every newly created to-do listens to the `'click'` event.
3. Finally, we get to the `complete()` function:

```
function complete (e) {
  const targetContainer = e.target.parentNode;
  const todo = targetContainer.querySelector('li') // I recommend adding a class name to the to-do li item to avoid targeting the wrong li element
  todo.classList.add('checked')
}
```

4. Now that we're adding a `"checked"` class to the to-do's li element, you can use the styling suggested by [Codigo de Senior](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13528510/codigo-de-senior):

```
ul li.checked {
  opacity: 0.3;
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```